# A problem of Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find a positive integer $n$ such that $n/2$ is a square, $n/3$ is a cube and $n/5$ is a ﬁfth power.

Above problem was given in the text *“An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers”* by *“Ivan Niven and Zuckerman".*

I tried to generalize the problem statement as:

**Find a positive integer $n$ such that $n/2$ is a square, $n/3$ is a cube, $n/5$ is a ﬁfth power, $n/7$ is a seventh power ... $n/p_{k}$ is a $p_{k}$-th power.**

I have found the solution for this and trying to generalize it more.
Now, How can I know that this work is authentic i.e. it has not been done by anyone earlier? Any sort of help is welcomed.

Comment: Erm... it may get me another warning, but I'd say it's unlikely anybody has researched that, before. It may be a nice puzzle, but it's uninteresting for professionals.

Comment: @ProfessorVector This has been done here alraedy at MSE, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987322/find-n-such-that-n-2-is-a-square-n-3-is-a-cube-and-n-5-a-fifth-power). I suppose it can be generalized easily.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I'm not surprised, I said it's a nice puzzle. But I understand the question more like "is it done in professional literature, or can I publish something like that?", and I don't think I have to explain why I think that's unlikely (except as an exercise in a textbook, maybe).

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yes, sure, this is what I think, too. I just wanted to show that this is, more or less, a well-known exercise.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Actually, my intention of asking the question was same as you understood and I do realize now that yes, it better be an exercise rather than a research paper.